# The suitability of procedural programs for graphical applications

Tags: c++, c, user-interface

Dear software engineers:

I am currently teaching a procedural programming unit (using the C language) to a group of Level 3 students in the UK. Here is [the Unit 16 Procedural Programming specification document](http://www.edexcel.com/migrationdocuments/BTEC%20Nationals%20from%202010/Unit-16-Procedural-Programming.pdf).

For a Distinction (higher level) task, the students must *"evaluate the suitability of procedural programs for graphical applications".*

It is possible to implement graphical applications using GTK and Qt, but it's also possible to create blinking text on a webpage (just because you can, it doesn't mean you should).

Many games and desktop applications are written in C++, so I suspect that object-oriented code is better for building graphical applications.

To reiterate, I need to *"evaluate the suitability of procedural programs for graphical applications".*

As a software engineer, how would you answer this question?

[Edit] For what it's worth, I received an excellent response to this question on [Quora](http://qr.ae/nzeD3).

Comment: You should ask this question on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: In my opinion OO code is easier to maintain, but the suitability of procedural programs for graphical applications depends highly of your definition of "graphical application". If any application which displays something is considered as "graphical application", then it is totally suited for it.

Comment: As others pointed out, GUI applications are usually very well suited to OO. Also, there are a lot of design patterns which apply for common GUI programming problems, like Decorator, MVC etc.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that object-oriented or procedural programs are "better", any more than writing algorithms in recursive or iterative style are "better".

Lots of wonderful code was written before object-orientation came along.

I think the styles have more to do with managing complexity.  Objects are state and behavior together in a single software component.  When you system maps well to objects, that style can be a good way to manage complexity.  It's worked well for GUI components like windows, buttons, etc.

But it need not be the only way.

I took an intro programming class in C at Stanford University in 1996, when C++ was just starting to take hold and neither Java nor C# existed.  They had students doing graphical programming using a very disciplined style that used well designed libraries and rigorous decomposition.  I would defy you to find better code.

Answer (score 1):

Even with object oriented programming, normally functions will eventually get called to perform some operations, and the code in those functions would be considered procedural. The main difference is how the code ended up calling those functions along with the parameters used by those functions.